# Conflict between gantt.sty and \framebox{}

Tags: packages, incompatibility, tufte

I've recently been using the [Edward Tufte](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/) inspired style file (the handout option) for my documents and a [Gantt chart](http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex_gantt_package.php) package. However, if I put `\usepackage{gantt}` in my preamble it prevents some code that previously worked fine (a set of frameboxes in a figure environment), from working. Is there any way around this issue? I assume it is something to do with the namespace of variables in each package, but I don't know enough latex markup to be able to inspect this.

I'm using TeXshop on a Mac with OSX, and have both .sty files in the folder where I am working. The problem appears to be with this structure:

```
\framebox(150,150){\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{image1.pdf}}
```

where I make a framebox (and place an image in the framebox, though the error occurs without any image in there).

Here is the code that I am using:

```
\documentclass[justified,marginals=raggedright]{tufte-handout}% justification

%\geometry{showframe}% for debugging purposes -- displays the margins

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gantt}

% Set up the images/graphics package
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{minibox}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

\title{Analysis}
\author[]{The authors}
\date{\today{}}  % if the \date{} command is left out, the current date will be used

% The following package makes prettier tables.  We're all about the bling!
\usepackage{booktabs}

% The units package provides nice, non-stacked fractions and better spacing
% for units.
\usepackage{units}

% The fancyvrb package lets us customize the formatting of verbatim
% environments.  We use a slightly smaller font.
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}

% Small sections of multiple columns
\usepackage{multicol}

% Provides paragraphs of dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% These commands are used to pretty-print LaTeX commands
\newcommand{\doccmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}% command name -- adds backslash automatically
\newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}% optional command argument
\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}% (required) command argument
\newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quote}\noindent}{\end{quote}}% command specification environment
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\textsf{#1}}% environment name
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% package name
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class name
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class option name

\begin{document}

\maketitle% this prints the handout title, author, and date

%\printclassoptions

\section{Objective of Analysis} \label{sec:objective}

\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\mbox{
\framebox(150,150){}
\framebox(150,150){}
\framebox(150,150){}
}
 \caption{Data sources used in this analysis;}
 \label{fig:map1} 
\end{figure*}
The analysis description is here


\end{document}
```

---

The contents of \listfile is as follows:

```
*File List*
tufte-handout.cls    2009/12/11 v3.5.0 Tufte-handout class
tufte-common.def    2009/12/11 v3.5.0 Common code for the Tufte-LaTeX styles
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
 xifthen.sty    2009/04/17 v1.3 Extended ifthen features
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 ifmtarg.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2a check for an empty argument
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   ifpdf.sty    2009/04/10 v2.0 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
titlesec.sty    2007/08/12 v2.8 Sectioning titles
titletoc.sty    2007/08/12 v1.6 TOC entries
hyperref.sty    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hypertext links for LaTeX
  ifvtex.sty    2008/11/04 v1.4 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2009/10/02 v1.5 Code for color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO
)
xcolor-patch.sty    2009/10/02 xcolor patch
  pd1enc.def    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2007/12/12 v1.2 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2007/09/09 v1.2 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
kvoptions.sty    2009/08/13 v3.4 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2009/07/30 v1.5 Key value parser with default handler support 
(HO)
   puenc.def    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2007/09/28 v1.0 Data type bit set (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2007/11/11 v1.1 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2009/09/23 v0.6 LuaTeX support for pdfTeX utility functions (
HO)
ifluatex.sty    2009/04/17 v1.2 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2009/08/05 v1.0 Some LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)

atbegshi.sty    2008/07/31 v1.9 At begin shipout hook (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
ragged2e.sty    2009/05/21 v2.1 ragged2e Package (MS)
everysel.sty    1999/06/08 v1.03 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
geometry.sty    2008/12/21 v4.2 Page Geometry
geometry.cfg
changepage.sty    2009/10/20 v1.0c check page and change page layout
paralist.sty    2002/03/18 v2.3b Extended list environments (BS)
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
letterspace.sty    2009/03/27 v2.3d Robust letterspacing (RS)
setspace.sty    2000/12/01 6.7 Contributed and Supported LaTeX2e package
  natbib.sty    2009/07/16 8.31 (PWD, AO)
bibentry.sty    2007/10/30 1.5 (PWD)
     Jan.bbl
optparams.sty    2004/08/14 v0.9 multiple optional parameters in macros
placeins.sty    2005/04/18  v 2.2
mathpazo.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
  helvet.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 
beramono.sty    2004/01/31 (WaS)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
fancyhdr.sty    
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2009/08/25 v0.04m Graphics/color for pdfTeX
dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
  svgnam.def    2007/01/21 v2.11 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
multicol.sty    2008/12/05 v1.6h multicolumn formatting (FMi)
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
   gantt.sty    
    tikz.sty    2008/02/13 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.27)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2008/02/20 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.21)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2008/01/15 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.6)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pgfsys.sty    2008/02/07 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.31)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/01/23  (rcs-revision 1.6)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2007/11/07 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.8)
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
 forloop.sty    2006/09/18 v3.0 For Loops for LaTeX
 minibox.sty    2009/04/21 v0.1 Another type of box.
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
   units.sty    1998/08/04 v0.9b Typesetting units
nicefrac.sty    1998/08/04 v0.9b Nice fractions
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
  lipsum.sty    2005/01/26 v1.0 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
  t1pplj.fd    2004/09/06 font definitions for T1/pplj.
 nameref.sty    2007/05/29 v2.31 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2008/08/11 v3.1 Data extraction from references (HO)
     Jan.out
     Jan.out
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Comment: This is probably not enough detail to diganose the problem.  Can you post a minimal example that shows the problem (i.e. a complete document that should load only `tufte-latex` and `gantt`, and a single framebox or whatever to show the error and/or bad output.)

Comment: @celenius - I had a similar problem sometime back, just try removing the xcolor or color package from gantt. Are you getting an options clash?

Comment: using `tufte-book` and `gant` doesn't cause any error!

Comment: @Alan, ok I'll do that shortly.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides - neither color or xcolor are in gantt as far as I can see.

Comment: I just updated my question which enables the problem to be reproduced; gantt.sty and the tufte-class needed to be used.

Comment: @celenius See my answer.  This has nothing to do with `tufte-handout`.

Comment: A snarky answer: Tufte thinks Gantt charts are bad visual design, so why would they appear in articles in his style? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer, because it is an answer to your question, even though your question is not, in fact, the right question.  There is no conflict between `tufte-handout` and `gantt.sty`; if you had produced a true minimal document to find what was causing the problem, you would have discovered this yourself. (This is why constructing minimal documents is both important and informative.)  Here is a *minimal* document that shows the problem you are having:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gantt} % comment out to see the correct output

\begin{document}

\framebox(150,150){}

\end{document}
```

This shows that there is a problem with `gantt.sty` and the `\framebox` command. A look at `gantt.sty` reveals the problem: it globally sets a value for `\unitlength` (1cm) instead of defining its own length.  `\unitlength` is also used in the `\framebox` command and which tries to make a square 150cm on a side, which is a little bigger than the page.

The fix to `gantt.sty` is relatively simple, but needs to be done carefully.

1. add `\newlength{\ganttunitlength}`
2. replace *all* instances of `\unitlength` in the style with `\ganttunitlength`
3. remove `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` from gantt.sty (they shouldn't be used in packages)
4. change `\usepackage` to `\RequirePackage` (equivalent package command)
5. add `\ProvidesPackage{gantt.sty}[2011/03/14 Gantt diagrams]` as the first line

Clearly `gantt.sty` wasn't quite ready for primetime.  I've sent its author a fixed version.

UPDATE: There is now a new version of `gantt.sty` posted on the [author's web site](http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex_gantt_package.php).

Comment: 6. Change question title to remove reference to tufte-article

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with your testfile. Put `\listfiles` into your
preamble and compare the file list, which is at the end of your log file:

```
 *File List*
tufte-handout.cls    2009/12/11 v3.5.0 Tufte-handout class
tufte-common.def    2009/12/11 v3.5.0 Common code for the Tufte-LaTeX styles
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
 xifthen.sty    2009/04/17 v1.3 Extended ifthen features
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 ifmtarg.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2a check for an empty argument
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   ifpdf.sty    2010/01/28 v2.1 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
titlesec.sty    2007/08/12 v2.8 Sectioning titles
titletoc.sty    2007/08/12 v1.6 TOC entries
hyperref.sty    2010/12/16 v6.81z Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2010/04/26 v1.7 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2010/04/01 v0.9 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2010/01/28 v1.3 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Provides hex, PDF name and string conversions 
(HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2009/12/12 v1.6 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2009/12/12 xcolor patch
letltxmacro.sty    2008/06/24 v1.3 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/02/22 v3.7 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2010/12/16 v6.81z Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2010/12/16 v6.81z Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2007/09/28 v1.0 Data type bit set (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2007/11/11 v1.1 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2010/03/25 v1.12 At begin shipout hook (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2010/12/16 v6.81z Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend.sty    2010/03/24 v1.5 Hooks at very end of document (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2010/03/16 v1.6 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2009/12/18 v1.1 Provides unlimited unique counter (HO)
ragged2e.sty    2009/05/21 v2.1 ragged2e Package (MS)
everysel.sty    2009/05/30 v1.1 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
changepage.sty    2009/10/20 v1.0c check page and change page layout
paralist.sty    2002/03/18 v2.3b Extended list environments (BS)
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
letterspace.sty    2010/01/10 v2.4 Robust letterspacing (RS)
setspace.sty    2000/12/01 6.7 Contributed and Supported LaTeX2e package
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
bibentry.sty    2007/10/30 1.5 (PWD)
optparams.sty    2004/08/14 v0.9 multiple optional parameters in macros
placeins.sty    2005/04/18  v 2.2
mathpazo.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
  helvet.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 
beramono.sty    2004/01/31 (WaS)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
fancyhdr.sty    
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2010/11/26 v0.05c Graphics/color for pdfTeX
dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
  svgnam.def    2007/01/21 v2.11 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
multicol.sty    2008/12/05 v1.6h multicolumn formatting (FMi)
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
   gantt.sty    
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
 forloop.sty    2006/09/18 v3.0 For Loops for LaTeX
 minibox.sty    2009/04/21 v0.1 Another type of box.
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
   units.sty    1998/08/04 v0.9b Typesetting units
nicefrac.sty    1998/08/04 v0.9b Nice fractions
fancyvrb.sty    2010/05/14
  lipsum.sty    2005/01/26 v1.0 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
  t1pplj.fd    2004/09/06 font definitions for T1/pplj.
 nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2008/08/11 v3.1 Data extraction from references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2009/12/18 v1.3 Cleanup title references (HO)
      zz.out
      zz.out
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2007/09/30 v1.0 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: I just did that; is there anything I should be looking for in particular?

Comment: @celenius: as seen, there are a lot of files with an older date. At least update `hyperref`, then delete your auxiliary files `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.idx` and run it again. And, by the way, it maybe a good idea, if you could provide the error message ...